# Unclear terms about Data visualization

Tags: python, json, csv, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a CSV file about customers' data, I converted it into JSON Dict type you can a single unreal person's data below.

```
{
"First Name": "Jonathan",
"Last Name": "Thomas",
"Marital Status": "married or civil partner",
"Sex": "Male",
"Age (Years)": 46,
"Retired": true,
"Distance Commuted to Work (miles)": 13.72,
"Employer Company": "Begum-Williams",
"Dependants": 1,
"Yearly Salary (\u00c2\u00a3)": 54016,
"Yearly Pension (\u00c2\u00a3)": 0,
"Address Street": {
  "Address Street": "00 Wheeler wells",
  "Address City": "Chapmanton",
  "Address Postcode": "L2 7BT"
},
"Credit Card Number": {
  "Credit Card Number": "4529436854129855",
  "Credit Card Start Date": "08/12",
  "Credit Card Expiry Date": "11/26",
  "Credit Card CVV": 583,
  "Bank IBAN": "GB37UMCO54540228728019"
},
"Vehicle Make": {
  "Vehicle Make": "Nissan",
  "Vehicle Model": "ATS",
  "Vehicle Year": 1996,
  "Vehicle Type": "Coupe"
}
```

I want to visualize data with seaborn and my tasks are right below there:

1. Perform univariate plots of the following data attributes:
   a) Age, calculating how many bins would be required for a bin_width of 5
2. Perform multivariate plots with the following data attributes

Could you explain the "univariate plots", "multivariate plots" and lastly "how many bins would be required for a bin_width of 5" terms for me?

I am confused about these terms. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Univariate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univariate) means "involving only one variable". For example, only involving the age. "Multivariate" just means "involving multiple variables".

To calculate the number of bins for a given bin width, you could subtract the smallest possible value from the largest, divide by the bin width, and add 1. Seaborn's `histplot` lets you directly set the `binwidth` and does the calculations for you.

Here is an example using the titanic dataset:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
# sns.histplot(data=titanic, x='age', bins=int(titanic.age.max()-titanic.age.min())//5+1 )
sns.histplot(data=titanic, x='age', binwidth=5, color='crimson')
```

[image: sns.histplot with binwidth=5]

With 2 variables ("bivariate"), you could e.g. create 2D `kdeplot`. Or a `scatterplot`. More variables can be represented either by [a 3rd dimension](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html), by color (called `hue` in Seaborn), by size and/or by marker style.
Which type of plot to choose heavily depends on your data and what you want to communicate with the plot.

Here is an example using 2 dimensions for a `scatterplot` with hue as a third. At the right, a 2D `kdeplot` is shown:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(14, 4))
sns.scatterplot(data=titanic, x='age', y='fare', hue='alive', ax=ax1)
sns.kdeplot(data=titanic, x='age', y='fare', fill=True, ax=ax2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot and sns.kdeplot in 2D]

Comment: Thank you JohanC for the wonderful explanation. I have similar question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979569/data-visualization-seaborn-unclear-term-question link. Could you also check it for me?